# Having Trouble Saving CSV With 100,000 Rows to MongoDB And Emitting Event After All Rows Are Saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv, heroku

I have a CSV document that is over 100,000 rows long, and each row includes Hourly Price Data which needs to be saved as its own database record.  I'd like for this operation to emit an event via EventEmitter after every row is saved, but instead, after saving all of the rows, the entire operation just repeats itself, and my Terminal once again says "Seeding Hourly Prices 2000-Current".  Can anyone help me fix this?

**Note:** I am using this [node-csv-string](https://github.com/touv/node-csv-string) package to process the CSV

**Bonus:** I'd like to deploy this on Heroku, but trying this operation occasionally results on memory errors, so if you have any advice on how to get around those, it would be greatly appreciated :)

**Read CSV File, Submit To Another Function To Process, And Wait For Callback...**

```
// SEED - HourlyPrices
exports.seed_hourly_prices = function(req, res) {
        console.log("Seeding Hourly Prices 2000-Current");

        // Seed Historical Data 2000 - 2014
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../../csv/hourlyprices_2000_2014.csv', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) { return console.log(err) };
            save_each_row(data, function(){ 
                console.log("Callback Heard");
                eventEmitter.emit('HistoricalDataSeeded');
            });
        });

}; // seed_hourly_price
```

**Process And Save Each Row**

```
save_each_row = function(data, callback) {
CSV.forEach(data,',', function(row, index) {
    if(row[0] && row[1] && row[0].indexOf('*') === -1 && row[1].indexOf('-') === -1) { // 1 hour out of the year contains an asterisk, I don't know why, but it marks a duplicate.  Don't add this.
        var splitDate = row[0].split(/[ ]+/); 
        var hour                        = splitDate[1];
        var day                         = splitDate[0];
        var full_date                   = row[0];
        var price                       = parseFloat(row[1]).toFixed(2);
        var thirty_day_rolling_average  = parseFloat(row[2]).toFixed(2);
        var system_demand               = parseFloat(row[3]).toFixed(2);

        if (hour === "24") {
            date = new Date(day+" 00:00:00");
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            date = moment.tz(date, 'America/Phoenix').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
            // Change day, hour, full_date results
            var hour      = '00';
            var day       = moment.utc(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            var full_date = day + " " + hour;
        } else {
            date = new Date(full_date + ":00:00");
            date = moment.tz(date, 'America/Phoenix').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
        };
        // Save Data
        var hourlyprice = new HourlyPrice({
            date:                                     date, 
            day:                                      day,
            hour:                                     hour,
            full_date:                                full_date,
            price:                                    price,
            thirty_day_rolling_average:               thirty_day_rolling_average,
            system_demand:                            system_demand
        });

        hourlyprice.save(function(err, pp){
                if (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR==========================", err);
                    console.log(hourlyprice)
                };
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Ommitted Row:" + index, row);
    };
}); //CSV()
}; // save_each_row
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fs.readFile` call will read the entire file into a single variable.  You need to split that into an array and then iterate over it, or use a module like readline, byline, or line-by-line to create a stream.